# Test a business logic which calls a public method that internally calls a private method

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I have an method in an Interface like so:

```
Task<bool> IsStudentAuthorizedAsync(StudentEntity studentEntity);
```

The implementation:

```
public async Task<bool> IsStudentAuthorizedAsync(StudentEntity studentEntity)
{
    // Check if the Student is activated for course
    var checkStudentForCourseTask = await this.CheckIfStudentIsEnabledForCourseAsync(studentEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return checkStudentForCourseTask;
}

private async Task<bool> CheckIfStudentIsEnabledForCourseAsync(StudentEntity studentEntity)
{
    var result = await this.tableStorage.RetrieveAsync<StudentTableEntity>(StudentEntity.Id, StudentEntity.CourseId, this.tableName).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result != null && result.IsActivated;
}
```

CheckIfStudentIsEnabledForCourseAsync is private method that checks by querying Azure Table Storage.

I am trying to Unit Test IsStudentAuthorizedAsync but am not able to move forward after the initial Setup call.

```
[TestClass]
public class AuthorizeStudentServiceBusinessLogicTests
{
    private Mock<IAuthorizeStudentServiceBusinessLogic> authorizeStudentServiceBusinessLogic;

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task IsStudentAuthorizedForServiceAsyncTest()
    {
        this.authorizeStudentServiceBusinessLogic.Setup(
                x => x.IsStudentAuthorizedAsync(It.IsAny<StudentEntity>()))
            .Returns(new Task<bool>(() => false));

        // What to do next!!!
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and will get me started on this path.
Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mock the access to the storage, not your business logic. To achieve this, you have to create one more layer:

```
public class Storage : IStorage {
    public Task<Student> RetrieveAsync();
}

public class BusinessLogic
{
    public BusinessLogic(IStorage storage)
    {
        _storage = storage;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsStudentAuthorizedAsync(StudentEntity studentEntity)
    {
        // Check if the Student is activated for course
        var checkStudentForCourseTask = await this.CheckIfStudentIsEnabledForCourseAsync(studentEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return checkStudentForCourseTask;
    }

    private async Task<bool> CheckIfStudentIsEnabledForCourseAsync(StudentEntity studentEntity)
    {
        var result = await _storage.RetrieveAsync<StudentTableEntity>(StudentEntity.Id, StudentEntity.CourseId, this.tableName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return result != null && result.IsActivated;
    }
}
```

Then you are able to mock the access to your storage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsStudentAuthorizedForServiceAsyncTest()
{
    Mock<IStorage> storageMock = new Mock<IStorage>();
    storageMock.Setup(x => x.Retrieve()).Returns(new Task<Student>()); // Return whatever you need
    var target = new BusinessLogic(storageMock.Object);

    var actual = target.IsStudentAuthorizedAsync();

    // Assert
}
```